# AVAudioPlayer, Checked All Errors, No Sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

My AVAudioPlayer plays **no sound**, but has **zero errors**. Spent almost two hours looking at docs, stackoverflow, and other forums.

I varied the recording durating from 1 to 3 to 10 seconds. Recorded audio file sizes were logged to be 27K, 33K, 54K. Makes sense. But no sound.

Tested on my iPhone 6 Plus and iPad Pro, both running iOS 9.2. Not sure if related, but I added these frameworks in XCode: Audio Toolbox, AVFoundation.

My code:

```
// Declared Global/Static Variables:
// Don't really need to be global, as I always code with ARC disabled,
// and I manually call retain later. Many SO posts had AVAudio problems
// due to ARC issues.
AVAudioPlayer* avap;
AVAudioSession* avas;
AVAudioRecorder* avar;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

// request permission (should be already granted)
avas = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[avas requestRecordPermission: ^(BOOL granted) {
    NSLog(@"audio record perm1 %s", granted ? "T" : "F"); } ];

// check again using a second way
NSLog(@"audio record perm2 %s", (avas.recordPermission
            == AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionGranted) ? "T" : "F");

NSError* nse1 = nil;
[avas setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
    // just in case something is wrong with my options,
    // I commented these out for now
    //withOptions:(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
            //|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker)
        error:&nse1];
NSLog(@"audio category error: %@", (id)nse1);

NSError* nse2 = nil;
[avas setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:&nse2];
NSLog(@"audio mode error: %@", (id)nse2);

NSError* nse25 = nil;
[avas setActive:true error:&nse25];
NSLog(@"audio active error: %@", (id)nse25);

// took this line below from another stackoverflow post
NSURL *furl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory()
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.m4a"]];

// commenting above line for "furl = ..", and
// uncommenting these below (taken from another post) did not help.
//NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
//NSURL *tmpFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp.m4a"]];
//NSURL* furl = tmpFileUrl ;

// using a null record setting did not help
//NSDictionary<NSString *, id> * recordSettings;

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary
    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0], AVSampleRateKey,
    [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
    nil];

NSError* nse3 = nil;
avar = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
    initWithURL:furl settings:recordSettings error:&nse3];
avar.delegate = self;
NSLog(@"audio record error: %@", (id)nse3);

const bool success = [avar recordForDuration:10.0];
NSLog(@"audio record succ: %d", success);

[avas retain]; // avoid any dealloc issues
[avar retain]; // avoid any dealloc issues
} // end of "void viewDidLoad"

- (void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)avar
successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    NSLog(@"recording done");
    [avar stop];

    // uncommenting these did not help
    //NSError* nse5 = nil;
    //AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    //[session setActive:NO error:&nse5];
    //NSLog(@"audio deactive error: %@", [(id)nse5 localizedDescription]);

    NSNumber *fileSizeValue = nil;
    NSError *fileSizeError = nil;
    [avar.url getResourceValue:&fileSizeValue
    forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey
            error:&fileSizeError];

    NSLog(@"filesize %@ error %@", fileSizeValue, fileSizeError);

    NSError* nse4 = nil;
    avap = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:avar.url
        error:&nse4];
    avap.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"audio play error1: %@", [(id)nse4 localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"volume %f len %f play %d", avap.volume,
            avap.duration, (int)[avap play]);
    [avap retain];
}

- (void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player
error:(NSError *)error {
    // never triggered, as you can see from the log output
    NSLog(@"audio play error2: %@", [(id)error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player
successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    NSLog(@"playing done %d", (int)flag);
}
```

My Output Log:

```
2015-12-15 01:37:01.972 sprite[916:327632] audio record perm1 T
2015-12-15 01:37:01.972 sprite[916:327632] audio record perm2 T
2015-12-15 01:37:01.972 sprite[916:327632] audio category error: (null)
2015-12-15 01:37:01.973 sprite[916:327632] audio mode error: (null)
2015-12-15 01:37:01.988 sprite[916:327632] audio active error: (null)
2015-12-15 01:37:02.014 sprite[916:327632] audio record error: (null)
2015-12-15 01:37:02.087 sprite[916:327632] audio record succ: 1
2015-12-15 01:37:14.499 sprite[916:327632] recording done
2015-12-15 01:37:14.555 sprite[916:327632] filesize 54354 error (null)
2015-12-15 01:37:14.558 sprite[916:327632] audio play error1: (null)
2015-12-15 01:37:14.590 sprite[916:327632] volume 1.000000 len 9.916000 play 1
2015-12-15 01:37:24.564 sprite[916:327632] playing done 1
```

Comment: **Cough**. ARC disabled? Seriously? **Cough** Global variables?

Comment: Have you tried playing a pre-recorded file? Have you checked the contents of the recording?

Comment: How do I get an URL to a pre-recorded file? Using voice recorder? And what do you mean check the contents? I logged the file sizes (shown above).

Comment: Add any sound file to your project, include it into the target, and load it, to see if playback works correctly. And to check recording, get the file you recorded from the device and try to play it on your Mac...